# WebSocket RegistryListener

Tags: websocket

```
public final class WebSocketRegistryListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {    
@Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
             if(event instanceof SessionDisconnectEvent) {
                SessionDisconnectEvent e = (SessionDisconnectEvent) event;
                Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.getSessionAttributes(e.getMessage().getHeaders());
              }
        }
}
```

e.getMessage().getHeaders(); which doesn't exsit.How to write it is correct?

Comment: Please!!! SomeBody help me slove this problem which is very urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, share, please, StackTrace on the matter.

There is no reason to have such a generic `ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent>` if you are going to get deal just with `SessionDisconnectEvent`. You can use the last one as generic type of the `ApplicationListener`.

And bare in mind `SessionDisconnectEvent extends AbstractSubProtocolEvent` with `getMessage()` is available since Spring `4.1.1`